# Unable to build this Observable

Tags: rx-java

To build a complete `User` entity, I need to perform this tasks:

1. Get a `UserResponse` (REST API response) from a `userId`
2. Get a `List<Role>` from a `userId`
3. Get a `Address` from the `UserResponse.addressId`
4. Build the `User` from the `UserResponse` and the `List<Role>` and the `Address`.

I tried this:

```
public Observable<User> getUserById(String userId) {    
    return Observable.zip(getUserResponse(userId), getRoles(userId), new Func2<UserResponse, List<Role>, User>() {
        @Override
        public User call(UserResponse response, List<Role> roles) {
            //I need the address here!
        }
});
```

But I don't know how to get the `Address` from the `UserResponse.addressId` using `AddressRepository`.

```
public interface AddressRepository {
    Observable<Address> getAddress(String addressId);
}
```

The `User` constructor looks like:

```
public User(String userId, Address address, List<Role> roles) { ... }
```

I hope you understand. It's hard to explain the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `cache()` operator:

```
public Observable<User> getUserById(String userId) {  
  Observable<UserResponse> response = getUserResponse(userId).cache();
  return Observable.zip(
    response,
    response.flatMap(new Func1<UserResponse, Observable<Address>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Address> call(UserResponse resp) {
            return addressRepository.getAddress(resp.addressId);
        }
    }),
    getRoles(userId), new Func3<UserResponse, Address, List<Role>, User>() {
        @Override
        public User call(UserResponse resp, Address ad, List<Role> roles) {
            //Now, I have all I need to build the User =)
        }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: But you are not using `cache()` operator above

Answer (score 1):

```
getUserResponse(userId).publish.autoConnect(2);
```

Will make it a ConnectableObservable and only start publishing where are there 2 subscribers and in this way you will be calling the backend only once.

getUserAddress() will call the getUserResponse and get the address out of it.

Now zip getUserResponse, getUserAddress and getRoles(userId) all together :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variant of `flatMap` do something like

```
public Observable<User> getUserById(String userId) {  
    return Observable.zip(
          getUserResponse(userId).flatMap(new Func1<UserResponse, Observable<Address>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Address> call(UserResponse resp) {
                return addressRepository.getAddress(resp.addressId);
            }
          },
          new Func2<UserResponse, Address, Pair<UserResponse,Address>>() {
            @Override
            public Pair<UserResponse,Address> call(UserResponse resp, Address addr) {
                return new Pair<UserResponse,Address>(resp,addressRepository.getAddress(resp.addressId));
            }       
          }),
          getRoles(userId),
          new Func2<Pair<UserResponse, Address>, List<Role>, User>(){
            @Override
            public User call(UserResponse resp, Address ad, List<Role> roles) {
            //Now, I have all I need to build the User
            }             
          }
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
public Observable<User> getUserById(String userId) {  
    return Observable.zip(
        getUserResponse(userId),
        getUserResponse(userId).flatMap(new Func1<UserResponse, Observable<Address>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Address> call(UserResponse resp) {
                return addressRepository.getAddress(resp.addressId);
            }
        }),
        getRoles(userId), new Func3<UserResponse, Address, List<Role>, User>() {
            @Override
            public User call(UserResponse resp, Address ad, List<Role> roles) {
                //Now, I have all I need to build the User =)
            }
        }
});
```

Any comment will be appreciated. Is it a good practice to "repeat" the call to `getUserResponse(userId)`? I didn't find another way to solve this.

Comment: getUserResponse(userId).publish.autoConnect(2); Will make it a ConnectableObservable and only start publishing where are there 2 subscribers and in this way you will be calling the backend only once.